# Plotting ground Tracks with Python only using trigonometry

Tags: python

I'm currently studying aerospace engineering, and I'm attempting to create a ground track plot in Python using data from a TLE file. I'm doing this without relying on explicit packages like AstroPy or skyfield. Instead, I'm using Gpredict and the Beyond package to compare my plot with the actual one generated by these tools.

I've encountered an issue with my ground track plot, as it differs from the real plot produced by Gpredict and Beyond. It appears that there is an offset in my ground track, and I suspect that it might be related to the way I'm handling time ("t") and the orbital period within the "for range()" loop section of my code.

Could you please provide any advice or suggestions to help me resolve this discrepancy? Below, I've included both my plot and the ground track generated by the Beyond package (verified by Gpredict) for reference.
My code is below as well.

My Plot:
[image]

Beyonds Plot:

[image]

My code:

'''

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy.constants import G, M_earth 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import astropy.units as u


# TLE Data
tle = '''BEESAT 9                
1 44412U 19038AC  23262.89659808  .00051662  00000+0  15010-2 0  9992
2 44412  97.6818 247.0298 0011987 342.9700  17.1138 15.35234033232668'''
#

# TLE data into two lines
tle_lines = tle.strip().split('\n')

# Name of cubesat
tle_line0 = tle_lines[0].strip()

#  line 1 and line 2
tle_line1 = tle_lines[1].strip()
tle_line2 = tle_lines[2].strip()


# To get the individual values
tle_elements1 = tle_line1.split()
tle_elements2 = tle_line2.split()


# Extract the orbital elements values from tle_elements
m =     float(tle_elements2[6]) #°
i =     np.radians(float(tle_elements2[2])) # rad
w =     np.radians(float(tle_elements2[5])) # rad
Omega = np.radians(float(tle_elements2[3])) # rad
e =     float("0." + tle_elements2[4])
M_mo=   round(float(tle_elements2[7]), 8) # rev/day
Epoch = tle_elements1[3][2:] # fraction day format xxx.xxxx
Epoch = float(Epoch)
year =  2000 + int(tle_elements1[3][:2]) # year in format 23
day =   int(np.floor(float(tle_elements1[3][2:]))) # day in format 001


# Get Julian Day
today = datetime(year, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=day)
today = Time(today)
jd = today.jd # Result: 2460207.5

#Julian Centuries converter
def JC_converter(jd):
    t = (jd - 2451545.0) / 36525
    return t
jc = JC_converter(jd) #Result 0.23716632443531827

# Siderial time for Greenwich
def greenW(jc): 
    # Equation: Theta= 1.753368559 + 628.3319707 * jc + 0.0000067707 * jc**2
    Theta= 1.753368559 + 628.3319707 * jc + 0.0000067707 * jc**2
    n = Theta / (2*np.pi) # We correct the number so Theta can't be greater than 2*PI or 360°
    n = np.floor(n)
    Theta = Theta - n*2*np.pi
    return Theta
Theta_k = greenW(jc)

# Pass since equinox 
w_sid= (2*np.pi) / 86164.0916 # angular siderial velocity of Earth
t_eqnx =  (2*np.pi - Theta_k) / (w_sid) #in w_siderial seconds

# Transforms epoch to seconds rounding to eigth decimal since midnight
def utc(epoch):
    n_epoch = round(epoch - int(epoch),8)
    #days to sec
    seconds = n_epoch*86400
    return seconds
epoch_sec = utc(Epoch) #  in sec

# Calculate the satellite's position at each time point
latitude = []
longitude = []

# Conversion
mean_prime = np.radians(m)
mean_motion = (M_mo * 2*np.pi) / 86400 # to rad/sec

# Time of Periapsis passage
tp = epoch_sec - (mean_prime / mean_motion)

# Orbital Period T of the cubesat
orbital_period =  (2*np.pi / mean_motion )#*86400 # 1 orbital period 86400 seconds in a day

time_elapsed = 0 # controlls the total of the seconds and if the seconds are equal to the Period orbit then stops to make the n orbits

# Seconds since midnight of today to get an acurrate time
now = datetime.now()
t = (now - now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)).total_seconds() 


for time in range(86400 - int(orbital_period),0,-10):    # A day has 86400 sec
    # Calculate mean anomaly propagation
    #  M = M_0 + n(t - tp)
    mean_anomaly = mean_prime + mean_motion * (time - t - tp)
    
    # Calculate eccentric anomaly using Newton's method
    E = mean_anomaly  # Initial guess for Eccentric Anomaly
    tolerance = 1e-8
    max_iterations = 1000

    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        f_e = E - (e * np.sin(E) - mean_anomaly)
        f_prime_e = 1 - (e * np.cos(E))

        E_new = (E - f_e) / f_prime_e
        # function returns the absolute value of the given number
        if abs(E_new - E) < tolerance:
            break

        E = E_new
    # Calculation new Epoch and time of the position of the cubesat    
    t_new =  tp + ((E - (e*np.sin(E))) /mean_motion)
    
    #True Anomaly
    true_anomaly = 2.0 * np.arctan2(
             np.sqrt(1.0 + e) * np.sin(E / 2.0),
             np.sqrt(1.0 - e) * np.cos(E / 2.0))
    
    # Calculate satellite's latitude and times negative since cubesats move from east to west
        
    satellite_latitude = np.arcsin(np.sin(i) * (np.sin(w + true_anomaly)))
    satellite_latitude = np.degrees(satellite_latitude) # Converting to degrees
    
    # Calculate satellite's longitude and times negative since cubesats move from east to west
    alpha = np.arctan2(np.cos(i) * np.sin(w + true_anomaly) , np.sin(i)*np.cos(w + true_anomaly) ) + Omega # Azimuth
    satellite_longitude = alpha - w_sid*(t_new - t_eqnx)
    satellite_longitude = np.degrees(satellite_longitude) # Converting to degrees
    satellite_longitude = (satellite_longitude + 180) % 360 - 180

    

    # Append latitude and longitude to the lists
    latitude.append(satellite_latitude)
    longitude.append(satellite_longitude)
    # Update time elapsed 
    time_elapsed += 10

    # one complete orbit has been completed
    if time_elapsed >= orbital_period:
        break 


# Sattelite velocity
mean_motion_unit = mean_motion
mean_motion_unit = mean_motion_unit* u.Unit("rad / s")
a_semiaxis = ((G*M_earth)**(1/3)) / ((mean_motion_unit) **(2/3))

cube_v = np.sqrt((G*M_earth)/a_semiaxis) 
cube_v = cube_v.value

# Load background image
background_image_path = r'D:\Satellite_Code\earth.jpg'
background_img = plt.imread(background_image_path)

# Create a figure and axis for the map with the background image
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15.2, 8.2))
ax.imshow(background_img, extent=[-180, 180, -90, 90])

# Plot the ground track
ground_track = ax.scatter(longitude, latitude, label="BEESAT 9 Ground Track", color='yellow', marker='o', s=2)
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude (degrees)")
ax.set_ylabel("Latitude (degrees)")
ax.set_title("BEESAT 9 Ground Track ")

# Initialize an empty point (scatter plot)
path, = ax.plot([], [], marker='o', color='blue', markersize=12)

#name of the cubesat in movement
name = ax.annotate(tle_line0, xy=(longitude[0], latitude[0]),
                    xytext= (longitude[0] -10, latitude[0] + 5), color = 'red' , fontweight='bold')

# Function to update the point's position in the animation
def orbit(i):
    path.set_data(longitude[i], latitude[i])
    name.set_position((longitude[i] - 10, latitude[i] +5 ))
    return path, ground_track, name

# Create the animation
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, orbit, frames=len(latitude), blit=True, interval = cube_v) #using the len of the latitude list for the frames

# Show the plot
ax.legend()
ax.grid(True, color='w', linestyle=":", alpha=0.4)

# Display the animation
plt.show()
```

'''